# Python Selenium Why can't I perform any action after opening a new tab and closing the first tab with Selenium?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to pull price data from a website by searching for a specific product, going to the product page, and grabbing the price. However, in order to go to the product page, it seems I need to open a new tab. When I close the old tab, I don't seem to be able to perform any other actions or find elements on the new page.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
import time

s = Service("C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)

driver.get("https://www.mcmaster.com/")
driver.maximize_window()

search = driver.find_element(By.ID, "SrchEntryWebPart_InpBox")
search.send_keys("91251A431") # search for part number  
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

try:

    part = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a[data-mcm-partnbr="91251A431"]'))
    )
    print(part.text)

    ActionChains(driver) \
        .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
        .click(part) \
        .key_up(Keys.CONTROL) \
        .perform()

    driver.close()

    element = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "PrceTxt")
    print(element.text)

except:
    print("Can't find price")
    driver.quit()
```

On the page in this example, I'd like to print out $8.59 per pack of 10. However, it seems no matter what code I put after driver.close(), the except clause is executed. I'm pretty sure my syntax and element names are correct, but maybe there is something I am missing? Do I need to select the new tab even after closing the old tab?

Comment: I have also tried adding driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) after driver.close(), but that doesn't seem to allow me to search for elements on that page either.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching the window before closing the older Tab.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could close a tab that wasn't active. As far as I know the driver.close() method does not take an argument, so how would I do that?

Comment: Selenium returns a Set of Window handles via ```getWindowHandles()``` in java.
I'm sure that it will be so in python too.

You can follow the steps as -

*Collect the set/list 
*In a for loop compare the values with the current window 
*If current window handle is not equal to loop's iterator, 
*change the driver window handle

*Similarly, you can close the other window handle

Comment: It seems using driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0]) with time.sleep() methods between other actions works. I think it's just that selenium is faster than the browser, so it needs time to load.